# Maven transitive dependency issue with maven-jetty-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

I have a project called Animal and it have two submodules Animal-models and Animal-server. The Animal-models have a compile time dependency xyz and the Animal-server have dependency on Animal-models jar. And the Animal-server generates a war file for running on jetty server. Everything is working fine currently. With the new changes dependency xyz is removed from Animal-models project and all of a sudden the server jetty run is failing with following exception. How to find out which jar is causing the issue?

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run (default-cli) on project ccd-event-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run failed: A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121:run: org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/guice/ModuleProcessor
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.8.v20171121
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-maven-plugin-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.24/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.5.0/maven-builder-support-3.5.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/resolver/maven-resolver-util/1.0.3/maven-resolver-util-1.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/3.1.0/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.24/plexus-interpolation-1.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.7.1/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.5/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.9.1/maven-artifact-transfer-0.9.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.0.1/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-quickstart/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-quickstart-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jaas/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-jaas-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-plus-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-jndi-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jmx/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-jmx-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-annotations-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/6.0/asm-6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/6.0/asm-commons-6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/6.0/asm-tree-6.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.4.8.v20171121/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.4.8.v20171121/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-client-api/1.0/javax.websocket-client-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-common-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-api-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.4.8.v20171121/apache-jsp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.5.23/apache-jsp-8.5.23.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.5.23/apache-el-8.5.23.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/ecj/3.12.3/ecj-3.12.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jstl/9.4.8.v20171121/apache-jstl-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/Users/crazyCow/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.ModuleProcessor
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: rest easy jar is missing. somehow your server code is looking for resteasy class ModuleProcessor. Just add it as a dependency and try.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs-all
 choose which ever version suits your need

Comment: Actually the resteasy jar exists.

Comment: can you verify if there is no version mismatch. also, check the runtime dependency tree to make sure the jar is available

Comment: Was able to resolve by changing some dependency jars from provided scope to compile and got it resolved. It's mainly because of the jar mismatch during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

[Scope provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) means that artifact is not packed within warfile, but is provided by container environment. Its typically used i.e. for servlet api.
As resteasy originates from jboss, they probably expect you to use their framework in jboss. Not in jetty. Hence default scope of the artifact seems to be "provided" - not packed in war.

But as you executed it in jetty,which is not jboss so that that it does not provide jboss jars and they are simply not there. So your "workaround" was [The right thing to do](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#d4e111).